# SQLAlchemy 2.0 session.execute() BULK INSERT respecting relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a web scraping project that uploads scraped data to a database using SQLAlchemy ORM. Lets use https://quotes.toscrape.com/ as an example

```
# models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship


Base = declarative_base()


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    birthday = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    bio = Column(Text, nullable=False)


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(31), unique=True, nullable=False)


class Quote(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'quote'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(ForeignKey('author.id'), nullable=False)
    quote = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)

    author = relationship('Author')
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary='quote_tag')


t_quote_tag = Table(
    'quote_tag', Base.metadata,
    Column('quote_id', ForeignKey('quote.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('tag_id',   ForeignKey('tag.id'),   primary_key=True)
)
```

Using the ORM unit-of-work paradigm I can simply add a Quote instance to the a session
Then call session.commit() and all 4 tables are populated appropriately.

```
# unit_of_work.py 

from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from models import *

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///quotes.db')

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
session = Session()

einstein_dict = {
    'name': 'Albert Einstein',
    'birthday': datetime(day=14, month=3, year=1879),
    'bio': 'Won the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics.'
}

change_dict = {'name': 'change'}
deep_thoughts_dict = {'name': 'change'}
thinking_dict = {'name': 'change'}
world_dict = {'name': 'change'}

quote_dict = {
    'quote': (
        "The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. "
        "It cannot be changed without changing our thinking."
    )
}

quote_instance = Quote(**quote_dict)
quote_instance.author = Author(**einstein_dict)
quote_instance.tags = [
    Tag(**change_dict), Tag(**deep_thoughts_dict), Tag(**thinking_dict), Tag(**world_dict),
]


# Adds with all relationships respected
session.add(quote_instance)
session.commit()
```

Using SQLAlchemy ORM Bulk Insert documentation https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html It seems you can get away from
unit of work, and use dict references and subqueries to insert / upsert data.

```
# bulk_insert.py

# Insert Authors
session.execute(
    insert(Author),
    [
        einstein_dict
    ]
)

# Insert Tags
session.execute(
    insert(Tag),
    [
        change_dict,
        deep_thoughts_dict,
        thinking_dict,
        world_dict,
    ]
)

# Insert Quotes
session.execute(
    insert(Quote).values([
        {
            'author_id': select(Author.id).where(Author.name == quote_instance.author.name),
            'quote': quote_instance.quote
        }
    ])
)

# Insert quote_tag association_table
values = []
for tag in quote_instance.tags:
    values.append({
        'quote_id': select(Quote.id).where(Quote.quote == quote_instance.quote),
        'tag_id': select(Tag.id).where(Tag.name == tag.name)
    })
session.execute(
    insert(t_quote_tag).values(values)
)

session.commit()
```

Is there a simple way to use SQLAlchemy 2.0 Bulk Insert to respect relationships? Something along the lines of

```
# ideal.py

session.execute(
    insert(Quote).instances([quote_instance])
)
session.commit()
```